# Timestamp format in application log

Tags: logging, timestamp

I am writing the logs for my cloud hosted application in JSON format.

Ex:

```
{"timestamp":1343205650,"app_name":"gmail","app_version":"2.45467","category":"Info","err_no":-1,"message":"Started","source_file":"appstartcrawler.cc","source_line":79}
```

The log is later parsed and indexed by Splunk.

My question is what format should I use for timestamp and why? Some of the options are:

1. ISO 8601 (ex: 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00)
2. RFC 2822 (ex: Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200)
3. Unix timestamp
4. MySQL format
   etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the article here](http://dev.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAADP6) options 1, 2 are preferred that include 4-digit year and timezone.

We are using ISO 8601 and it works perfectly.